# Summarising data from a Q/A table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table that consists of questions and answers as shown:
[image: Table 1]

I need to write a query that summarises it By question, listing the answers for each question, like below:

[image: Required Summary Table]

I seem to be getting hung up on the best way to write this query, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation like this:

```
SELECT t.Form,t.Sequence,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.question_id = 101 then t.Answer end) as First_Name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.question_id = 101 then t.Answer end) as Last_Name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.question_id = 101 then t.Answer end) as Age
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY t.Form,t.Sequence
```